# How to inherit UserControl form a abstract UserControl (without the designer messing up)?

Tags: c#, wpf, abstract, user-controls, inheritance

I've got a Control (mySubControl) which inherits from a UserControl (myAbstractControl) which is abstract.
Now inside the Designer of mySubControl, there's always an error saying: Can't create instance of myAbstractControl.

I think the VS2010 Designer is trying to use the constructor of the myAbstractControl.

How can I prevent him from resulting in an error ?

This whole thing seems a bit creepy.

Let's see. I have a abstract BaseClass.

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(ConcreteControlProvider))]
public abstract class AbstractControl : UserControl
```

It has a constructor containing code, which should be used by any inheriting class.

```
public AbstractControl(SuperVar myImportantSuperVar)
{
    myPrivateSuperVar = myImportantSuperVar;
    this.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(TreatMySuperVar);
}
```

Besides that, it needs the empty constructor to match the UserControl inheritance

```
public AbstractControl() {/*You won't really use me*/}
```

Now when there's a inheriting class (written by evil colleagues).

```
public partial class ConcreteControl: AbstractControl
```

It needs its own constructor and doesn't use my very important SuperVar treating method.

```
public ConcreteControl(SomeOtherVar notMyVar)
{
    // Do some useless things here
}
```

So there are TWO Problems now. Still I don't know why my designer is messing up and additionally my abstract classes construtor, vars and methods are ignored.

I already tried to use TypeDescriptionProviders (overriding GetReflectionType and CreateInstance) as noted in the linked entry, which didn't make difference.

So how can I solve this issues ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817107/abstract-usercontrol-inheritance-in-visual-studio-designer

Comment: Well nice, it links to another page http://wonkitect.wordpress.com/2008/06/20/using-visual-studio-whidbey-to-design-abstract-forms/ but this one seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Is a constructor with the same signature defined in your inheritor?

Comment: I have a generic solution in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12594795/39396) to the other question.