# User defined property for User Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I've tried implementing a user defined property for my user control class by including the code :

```
Private title As String = ""

<Category("Titles"),
Description("Title of the application")>
Public Property MyTitle() As String
    Get
        Return title
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        title = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But the property Title still does not appear when looking at the [Design] layout and in the properties.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Drop an instance of your control on a `Form` and you can see the property in property grid if you select the control. The properties you see in designer of your control are properties of its base class `Control`. But when you put an instance of it on a `Form` the properties are properties of the instance of your control. This is the way that designer works.

Comment: Also for more information take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32299687/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks! Marked as duplicate