# WinForms Designer should run method from CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a small WinForms application with only a button at the Center of the main window. That's button text is **Button 1**.
The constructor in code behind (F7) change thats button text to **Hello World** after the call to **InitializeComponent**.

The runtime Shows "Hello World" but at design time the Designer Shows "Button 1".  What is the correct way in WinForms to run custom UI-code. If I manually put that code into the designer-file than my changes gets overridden next time when designer is saved.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button1.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the Button Text from Properties window if you'd like so it shows the same as Run Time.

Comment: You can also enter the form designer (`Form1.designer.cs`) to manually edit your controls properties.

Comment: The constr of `Form1` gets only executed once you launch your application, that's the intention. But if you set the `Text` right away after you initialised all the objects and stuff you can already set the `Text` in the designer class. By the way, there is no *code behind*, this class and the designer class are `partial` classes, so the both form together one single class (`Form1`), but the designing stuff of `Form1` got outsourced into the designer class to simplify code for better understanding and a more clear overview.

Comment: @SeckinCelik:
Of course the real problem is a bit more complicated (setting Icons of ribbon button by an enum instead of a resource by using a special method).

Comment: @L.Guthardt:
They are partial but it seems that the designer runs the design-file in another context. Because if you call a custom method from the designer files initialize method then the designer will show an error with that message: "Method 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.xxx' not found."

Comment: Take a look at this post about [how designer works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32299687/3110834).

Answer (score 1):

Title say:

> WinForms Designer should run method from CodeBehind?

Designer is tricky, since you are *designing* the new type `Form1` it will actually create an instance of base class `Form` and then let you to modify it, generating `designer.cs` and resources for you.

To ensure code will run in designer, you have to move it to base class. This can be achieved by making *custom control*:

```
public class MyForm: Form
{
    protected button1;

    public MyForm()
    {
        button1 = new Button { Text = "Hello World" }; // here
        Controls.Add(button1);
    }
}
```

Now when you inherit new form from it all those forms will have a button.

```
public partial class Form1 : MyForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

To make it easier for new users there is `UserControl`. While editing it the changes in code behind are not show in designer directly. But once you finish, compile it and add it to another form - designer will be running your code there when editing that another form. You will have to re-compile after every change to code behind of user control though.