# Declare BindingSource.DataSource as generic

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

i'm trying to declare bindingSource as generic in a control generic

```
public partial class ABMControl<T> : UserControl
{
    public ABMControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
partial class ABMControl<T>
{
    ...
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...
        this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(T)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But in the designer this is the problem:

> Failed to parse method 'InitializeComponent'. The parser reported the
>   following error 'Type parameters are not suppported Parameter name:
>   typeSymbol'. Please look in the Task List for potential errors.

[image: But in the designer this is the problem]

Comment: when i'm binding a bindingsource to a entity, from the designer this is the syntax is
this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof("entity")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent designer error, set data source of binding source in constructor.

When you put a piece of code in constructor of your control designer deserializer will not try to parse it. It also will not run in design time of your control, while in run-time and also for derived control, it will run.

Here is what you should have to prevent error:

```
public partial class ABMControl<T> : UserControl
{
    public ABMControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(T)
    }
}
```

For more information about how designer works take a look at the following post, specially take a look at the example which contains a couple of errors but shows the designer:

- [Can't view designer when coding a form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32298865/3110834)