# Multiple abstract form inheritance

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have an abstract base control `BaseControl` for which I resolved the non-display of the child forms using [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17661276/2490877).

Now, I have a lot of controls sharing some common properties for which I want to create an intermediate abstract class to regroup the different common properties and force all descendants to implement some other properties.

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(AbstractControlDescriptionProvider<BaseControl, UserControl>))]
public abstract partial class BaseControl : UserControl {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
 [TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(AbstractControlDescriptionProvider<BaseControl2, BaseControl>))]
public abstract partial class BaseControl2 : BaseControl {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, the designer complains about not being able to create an instance of abstract class `BaseControl2` for my descendant controls.

Any suggestion of how to resolve this?

Comment: I don´t understand your problem. Can´t you simply create a class deriving from `BaseControl2` and instantiate this one?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you may want to take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262541/abstract-generic-usercontrol-inheritance-in-visual-studio-designer).

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize how the `AbstractControlDescriptionProvider` works - if the type is abstract, it replaces it with the non-abstract base type.

You specified an abstract type as the non-abstract base type, so obviously it can't work :)

Comment: yes, so I tried to replace with the `UserControl` instead of the `BaseControl` but it doesn't work either...

Comment: @neggenbe Well, you'd need to provide a complete piece of code that actually shows your problem to get real help, but note that the `AbstractControlDescriptionProvider` doesn't traverse the type hierarchy - it only deals with one possible abstract class. And `TypeDescriptorProviderAttribute` is inherited, so in most cases you really need to have no more than one in the whole hierarchy - the designer doesn't even see the second type description provider.