# c# windows forms create generic form

Tags: c#, winforms

**I am trying to create a generic user control that inherits parent that also generic.
*something like this*:-**

```
public partial class UserControlBase<T> : UserControl { }
public partial class UCParent<T> : UserControlBase<T> { }
public partial class AnalysisUC<T> : UCParent<T> { }
```

**the UCParent & AnalysisUC designers  not works fine. get this error**

> Cannot create an instance of
>   AnalysisSys.UI.infrastructure.UCParent`1[T] because
>   Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

[image]

*thanks a lot for your help.*

Comment: The designer doesn't know how to create that type of form or control.

Comment: [Windows Forms Designer - Generic Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33112824/3110834)

Comment: [Abstract generic UserControl inheritance in Visual Studio designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262541/abstract-generic-usercontrol-inheritance-in-visual-studio-designer)

Comment: Thanks dear for your perfect answer