# Error inheriting UserControl base class while working with Visual Studio designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, inheritance, user-controls

Well the title should actually explain the problem quite well. Consider I create a new `UserControl`, however in my application many of those elements share a common code, and they are part of a "subgroup" of user controls.

The logical thing is to "inject" a class between the generated `CustomUserControl` and `UserControl`;

Something akin to:

```
public abstract class CommonCustomControl : UserControl 
{ 
    public CommonCustomControl(int v, string other) {
    }
}
public partial class CustomUserControl : CommonCustomControl
{ 
    CustomUserControl(int v, string other) : base(v, other) {
    }
}
```

Now the problem with this is, is that the class is only "partially" generated by visual studio. So changing the generated `CustomUserControl` class gives an error:
  "Base class differs from declared in other parts"

How can I prevent this error? While still being able to actually design my user control element in visual studio's gui designer?

I have tried already the answer provided by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817107/abstract-usercontrol-inheritance-in-visual-studio-designer). But it seems to not work at all. (Maybe since that talks about winforms instead of the WPF version)

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(AbstractControlDescriptionProvider<InterfaceHandler, UserControl>))]
public abstract class CommonCustomControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly int _v;
    private readonly string _other;

    public CommonCustomControl(int v, string other) {
        _v = v;
        _other = other;
    }
}

public partial class CustomUserControl : CommonCustomControl
{
    public CustomUserControl(int v, string other) : base(v, other) {
    }
}
```

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have your C# code on view here but I'll take a punt at what this might be.

The `UserControl` you are declaring inherits from a base class.
The `UserControl` is also a `partial class`.

Partial classes normally mean that there is other code for this class elsewhere.

The error is stating that the base class is different between the two partial classes.

If you do not have your own second `partial class` for this `UserControl` (i.e. it is not just a class, but an actual User Control), then I assume the rest of the definition will be in the `XAML`.

Depending on how you are implementing your controls:

You may have this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NamespaceHere.CustomUserControl"> ... </UserControl>
```

It should look like this:

```
<CommonCustomControl x:Class="NamespaceHere.CustomUserControl"> ... </CommonCustomControl>
```

If not, could you show your `XAML` too?

Comment: Ah I can do such things too.